# My Android App Requests Location Permission I Didn't Ask For

Tags: android, android-location, android-permissions

Looking at the final manifest after a build it includes two extra permissions that I didn't ask for. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION.

I'm running a gradle build. I saw another post saying to declare a uses-sdk section with a minSdkVersion however that didn't help.
Here's what i tried:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

I also looked through the manifest on all of my dependencies and I don't see anything that could be adding it.

```
com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
compile 'com.sababado.circularview:library:1.0.0'
```

Where are the permissions coming from?

Comment: This `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` imports everything. Remove it. This has been asked many times before.

Comment: Yup this is a duplicate. Thank you for the link. I searched for a bit and didn't come across this one.

Answer (score 3):

App manifest lists what your app requires, even you did not put it explicitly in **your** Manifest file. In fact the final Manifest is a result of merge of your AndroidManifest.xml and all the manifests used dependencies (these usually referenced via gradle's `compile ...`) provide.

If you wonder which dependency contributes to your final permission requirements, you can check manifest merger report file (check `<PROJECT>\app\build\outputs\logs` folder and check for `uses-permission#PERMISSION`, i.e.:

```
uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:11:5
MERGED from com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0:22:5
```

Here's blog post you may also want to check: [Hey, Where Did These Permissions Come From?](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html)

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Service might have asked the permission. As you know it shows the number of user on the basis of their location and country.

Comment: It isn't Google Analytics. I just reverted back to a state before I added the library and it is still there.

Comment: I edited the answer. Sorry for the previous one.